# Eigenvalue ODE in Spherical Coordinates--Numerical

Tags: eigensystem, differential-equations

I wish to solve an eigenvalue problem:

$$\nabla^{2}f=Ef $$

If I assume spherical symmetry $f(r,\theta,\phi)=f(r)$, I can reduce the problem to 1D:

$$(\frac{2}{r}\frac{d}{dr}+\frac{d^{2}}{dr^{2}})f=Ef$$

My boundary conditions are $f(r=0)=0$ and $f(r=L)=0$, where $L$ is the size of the discrete grid.

I am attempting to solve this problem using a orthogonal basis set expansion, but the issue I am experiencing is the divergence of $r$ at $r=0$. Is there a better method for solving this type of problem? How can I accommodate the singularity?

Comment: You could multiply both sides of the equation by $r$. Does that work?

Comment: @nicoguaro Yes, but then I no longer have an eigenvalue equation. I guess my question is more along the lines of what method is best suited to solve the above problem.

Comment: That's not quite true. You might have something similar to a [Sturm-Liouville problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) with a weighting function.

Comment: @nicoguaro Ok, I see what happens. What would be a simple to implement solution for such a problem? Preferably something other than a shooting method? There seems to be a wide variety of different methods out there. I would like to single out one instead of trying many different types.

Comment: Have you checked these posts: [1](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21732/9667), [2](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/19679/9667)?